# Why does my class constructor feels bloat and faulty?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I'm fairly new to OOP and I'm struggling with setting up my classes. I'm working on a project where I have the following classes: `dogTag`, `dog`, `user`.

This is my current `dogTag`class:

```
class DogTag
{
    const POST_TYPE = 'dog-tag';
    private ?int $id = null;
    private string $number;
    private ?Dog $dog;
    private ?User $user;
    private bool $isActive = false;
    private bool $isLost = false;
    private string $generationDate;
    private ?string $activationDate;
    private string $productionStatus;

    public function __construct($id = null, string $number, ?Dog $dog = null, ?User $user = null, bool $isActive, bool $isLost, string $generationDate, ?string $activationDate, string $productionStatus)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->dog = $dog;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
        $this->isLost = $isLost;
        $this->generationDate = $generationDate;
        $this->activationDate = $activationDate;
        $this->productionStatus = $productionStatus;
    }
```

Let me explain the functionality of the dog tag. Dog Tags are being generated by a generator and stored into the database. So a dog tag only needs the following arguments when being generated: `number` (this is a unique generated number and not a unique database ID), `isActive`, `isLost` (could be optional), `generationDate`, `productionStatus`. All other arguments are not necessarily needed for the generation.

So my first question is: **"Do I need to set the optional arguments in the contructor?"**.

Let me explain why I did this for the moment. When a user receives the unique dog tag number they can activate the dog tag. Therefor I use a method called `activateDogTag`. For a dog tag to be activated it needs to be attached to a user. Therefor I use the `$user` argument in the constructor.

Here comes my second question: **"Should I use a method `setUser(User $user)` where I inject the user object into the `dogtag` class?"**.

Another problem that I'm struggling with is that I also use an `id` argument. This will be a bit harder to explain why I'm using this and why it feels wrong.

I'm also using the `dogTag` class to I can instantiate it with all the data from the database. For the moment I have a static `DogTag::get($id)` method. This class grabs the data from the database by the ID an instantiates a new `DogTag` class where I fill all the arguments with the data received from the database.

For information: I'm using WordPress)

```
public static function get($postId): ?DogTag
    {
        $post = get_post($postId);
        
        if (empty($post)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        $dogTagId = $post->ID;
        $generationDate = $post->post_date;
        
        $dogTagNumber = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dog_tag_number', true);
        $dogId = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dog_id', true);
        
        if (empty($dogId)) {
            $dog = null;
        } else {
            $dog = Dog::get($dogId);
        }
        
        $userId = $post->post_author;
        $user = $userId ? User::get($userId) : null;
        $isActive = get_post_meta($dogTagId, 'dog_tag_is_active', true);
        $isLost = get_post_meta($dogTagId, 'dog_tag_is_lost', true);
        $activationDate = get_post_meta($dogTagId, 'dog_tag_activation_date', true);
        $productionStatus = get_post_meta($dogTagId, 'dog_tag_production_status', true);
        
        $dogTag = new self($dogTagId, $dogTagNumber, $dog, $user, $isActive, $isLost, 
        $generationDate, $activationDate, $productionStatus);
        $dogTag->post = get_post($postId);
        
        return $dogTag;
    }
```

This way all the arguments are filled and are available within the class.

**So where am I going wrong and what I'm I doing correct?** The problem is that I can't really find any solution in my online courses for these problems as they don't go this deep.

Where I'm also struggling is eg with the static activation class (DogTag::activateDogTag):

```
public static function activateDogTag()
    {
        // Here goes the form
        $dogTag = self::getDogTagByDogTagNumber('4OV9NHOPXLAB6X9B');
        // $dogTag = self::getDogTagByDogTagNumber('VBD6JZODTZ6L4YU7');
        
        if (!$dogTag) {
            var_dump('no dog tag with this ID found');
        }
        
        if(true == $dogTag->getIsActive()) {
            var_dump('Dog Tag is already active');
        }
        
        if ($dogTag->getUser()) {
            var_dump('user is set');
            return;
        }
        
        var_dump('Activate');
        
        $userId = get_current_user_id();
        
        if (0 === $userId) {
            var_dump('not logged in as a user');
        }
        
        $dogTag->setIsActive(true);
        
        $dogTag->setUser($userId);
        
        $user = $dogTag->getUser();
        
        var_dump($dogTag);
        
        // Update dog Tag
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'dog-tag',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_title' => $dogTag->getNumber(),
            'post_date' => $dogTag->generationDate,
            'post_author' => $dogTag->getUser()->getId(),
            'meta_input' => [
                'dog_tag_number' => $dogTag->getNumber(),
                'dog_tag_is_active' => $dogTag->getIsActive(),
                'dog_tag_is_lost' => $dogTag->getIsLost(),
                'dog_tag_production_status' => $dogTag->getProductionStatus(),
            ]
        ];
        
        var_dump($args);
        $postId = wp_update_post($args);
        $dogTag->setId($postId);
        
        return $dogTag;
    }
```

Is this a good practice:

```
$dogTag->setIsActive(true);
$dogTag->setUser($userId);
$user = $dogTag->getUser();
```

and after the data is stored into the database via `wp_update_post` by setting the `id` property via `DogTag->setId($postId)`?

Comment: I only read your title question and glanced at the code, but PHP 8 has [Constructor Property Promotion](https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8) with the explicit goal of removing most of that boilerplate. Also, if you have a function parameter (including in a constructor) that is optional (has a default value), all subsequent parameters ‘must be optional](https://3v4l.org/EJTQP ), too, as of PHP 8.

Comment: Another question. Is it also a good idea to use objects here such as eg `User user` to quickly access the property data from the `DogTag` class?

Comment: "Is it also a good idea" is subjective. As the other person noted, working code is what matters first and foremost. If the code "feels" wrong, you might be able to refactor, but get it working, first. Generally, using properties is a common pattern to access things. Whether those things are objects or primitives doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks. Were I mostly doubt and struggle with is with my Dog Tag activation class where I instantiate the DogTag object and start manipulating it by first grabbing the data out of the database and then start manipulating the class.

Comment: I'm still going to talk more philosophically, so don't take this as an absolute or a requirement or anything like that. It is a very common best practice for many people that entities that represent a "thing" (such as Dog Tag) that probably lives in a database, should be pure and simple (and honestly dumb). For instance, if you can pass a UserID to that entity and it "knows" how to talk to the database, perform error handling and such, and return a User object, many people would recommend separating those two concerns somehow, such as a global utility function "getDogTag($tag, $userId)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it works then you are not doing anything wrong.

###### Question 1

It's usually better practice to start with required parameters, followed by optional parameters, if it feels too bloated you could remove all optional parameters from the constructor and create setters for those.

###### ID/Fetching

What you have here is fine, you could create another class `DogTagFactory`/`DogTagRepository` which handles the creation/database process for you if you and reduce bloat.

Overall try not to get too stuck in the chase of "perfect" best practice, it's always going to depend on the situation and usually in the end it does not even matter all that much.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yeah, you always want to go with best practices but all those patterns make it really hard but I want to get the core structure correct. I don't want to end up driving a car with the steering in the trunk, you know. BTW your profile name sounds Dutch. If so 'aangename kennismaking'. I'm Dutch (Belgium) too ;-)

Comment: @FilipVanReeth Hey neighbour ;) Honestly your code is better than most wordpress plugins i've seen, Might want to work on separating it a bit like i said, separate class for instantiation logic to increase testability and clear bloat, then look at what properties are really optional, like, is ID really optional? it's derived from post ID so i don't think it can be, You asked about whether storing user is good practice, it really depends on if you need it or not. if you rarely need it you can change it to a `user_id` field so you can fetch it on demand.

Comment: Great comment. If you like or want I can give you access to the private repo. Just contact me via Twitter via @filipvanreeth